# How to output browser console logs in php and codeception

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

I am trying to find a way where I can print out browser console logs of a page. Is there a Javascript way to do this, or a native selenium script? I am using php and codeception

Comment: Why do you need such a thing, why is using the browser's console window not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java and selenium this method work in my chrome.Hope it will give you some idea

```
 public void analyzeLog() {

LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
    System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
    //do something useful with the data
}
}
```

Comment: class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    
    {
        String a[]={
              "\"env\":\"production\"",
               "\"lat\":\"22.81348\"",
                "\"lng\":\"89.56723\"",
                "\"country\":\"USA\""};
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);
            
            }
        
    }